# How to make rotate animation smooth?

Tags: android, animation, rotation

I am trying to move a needle image on meter with the help of `RotateAnimation`.
I am using the following code

```
mNeedleAnimation = new RotateAnimation(mTransformedDegree, mTransformedDegree + degreeToRotate,x, y);
mTransformedDegree += degreeToRotate;
mNeedleAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
mNeedleAnimation.setDuration(200);
mNeedleAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
mNeedleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
mNeedle.startAnimation(mNeedleAnimation);
```

Problem with this code is that needle jumps directly from 1 value to other. But i want the needle movement to be smooth. I also tried to use the `setInterPolator` as linear for the animation but it didn't worked as expected.

Can anyone help me for the same?

Updating the needle view code

```
final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mNeedle.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onPreDraw() 
    {
        mNeedleHeight= mNeedle.getHeight();
        mNeedleWidth = mNeedle.getWidth();

        return true;
    }           
});
```

Comment: Can we also see the code of the needle view, it's drawing code must be efficient to get a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [animation interporlators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) and instantiate any sub-class and set it to the animation.

```
mNeedleAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
```

Comment: I tried setting the mNeedleAnimation.setInterPolator(new AccelerateDeaccelerateInterPolator()); and

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this :

```
rotanim = new RotateAnimation(
                (float) (((currenspeed) * 360) / 180),
                (float) (((nextspeed) * 360) / 180),
                (float) imgNeedle.getWidth() / 2,
                (float) imgNeedle.getHeight());

        rotanim.reset();
        rotanim.setDuration(400);
        rotanim.setFillAfter(true);
        imgNeedle.startAnimation(rotanim);
```

> and it works good for me..